# Apache Storm, n bolts store data n pipelines

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have an Apache Storm topology that have 1 spout (data from kafka) and 10 bolts that compute data and then try to storage. My problem is that a have 10 pipelines that try to store data from Storm to a single instance of Mongodb.
What's the best solution for this problem? I have experience with Apache Cassandra, but this is a project that is developed by 2 teams, and 1 team have no experience with Cassandra. Can Mongodb handled this? Apache Hadoop?

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data locally. Then create an microservice to send the data remotely in 1 by 1 pipeline.